# SSRS copying from PDF to WORD and weird characters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I hope you help me a bit

I got problem with reporting services. I'm using reporting services to generate and export few reports to a pdf file .

Let's just cut to the chase.
After saving (export) a report to pdf file I need to have possibility copying content of document to .doc/.docx file type.

Right now I can do it of course, but after copying all of content from pdf to doc I got weird characters like :

The pdf file looks good!
All fonts seems to be embedded (in file - properties - fonts).

I noticed that the problem occurs with polish characters like ą, ę, ć, ł etc.
If word/expression contains one of those character text after copying is weird.

Fount that:
"Microsoft Word does not directly support conversion from Adobe Portable Document Format (PDF). PDF is the format in which documents are saved for viewing and exchange in the Adobe Acrobat Reader and Adobe Acrobat Exchange for Windows."

Hmm and in addition those characters like ą / ł are not searchable even inside PDF.

IS there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Why are you converting the PDF file to a word document? You can just export the report as a word document from the report viewer... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239307.aspx

Comment: It's hard to explain. I'm not trying to convert PDF file to word document. I just need to make the text look good after copying from pdf.

Comment: Instead of first exporting it to PDF en then manually copying it to Word, you can just export the report directly to Word. Have you looked at the link from my previous comment?

Comment: Files (pdf) are automatically exported on server and sent to the customer.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/137824/pdf-has-garbled-text-when-copy-pasting

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The question is not about how to get around the copy-paste situtation. It's surely a requirement from the users. Did you find any solution to your problem?